# How to continue session from iPhone App to a Mobile Website?

Tags: iphone, session, uiwebview

How does continue session from iPhone App to a Mobile Website Works?

For example, Facebook App, some of its features will direct to an internal browser.

Will you still use that same session or there is a different session key for that Mobile Website. Basically I don't want to login again when I will be redirected to My application's Internal Browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook uses a technique called OAuth2 to authorize other applications with the Facebook service, you can check out how to use OAuth2 for the iPhone [here](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/oauth2-for-iphone-and-ipad-applications.html). Basically, you send your site user credentials (username and password) and get an access token back. Then, you can use that token within the app to find out information about the user, do actions by the user, etc.. Finally, if you need to access the actual website of your application, the same access token should allow you to sign into the website without having to re-enter the username and password.

Comment: can i use this for my own website authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think that OAuth2 is used for external services trying to access your website, it says "OAuth provides a method for users to grant third-party access to their resources without sharing their passwords." For your own site, usually you have a flag in the session data saying the user is logged in instead of using an access token. (For more OAuth2 stuff, you can check out [the introduction](http://hueniverse.com/2010/05/introducing-oauth-2-0/)